# Issue when the initialization method's parameter with default value

Tags: ios, xcode, init

I am make a init method in my project for a certain class, basically I want to wrap a local Notification class.

Because my local notification has only one sound and I want to put it as a default when the class is initialized as following:

```
    override init(notificationTitle:String, subtitle:String, sound = UNNotificationSound.init(named: AppSettingManager.share.loadFocusNotificationSound()), categoryId:String ) {

    super.init()
}
```

because the sound parameter's value is store in the NSUserdefault and I want to set the sound's value when the class is initialized.

However, Xcode complains as

> Unnamed parameters must be written with the empty name '_'

[image]

How can I approach this? Any other way to solve this? thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you’re misinterpreting this error. It’s just tell you you that your syntax is wrong, that you want to give that parameter a name, or explicitly declare it has no name. You’re just missing `:` for `sound`. Eg `override init(notificationTitle: String, subtitle: String, sound: UNNotificationSound = UNNotificationSound(named: AppSettingManager.share.loadFocusNotificationSound()), categoryId: String ) { ... }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `sound =` to `sound:`

```
override init(notificationTitle:String, subtitle:String, sound: UNNotificationSound.init(named: AppSettingManager.share.loadFocusNotificationSound()), categoryId:String ) {
    super.init()
}
```